# How can I configure network manager (via command line) to only ever connect to a wireless network with a particular ssid?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I'm away from work for the week and need to ssh into my office computer (Ubuntu 12.04) regularly to do work.  Unfortunately, my particularly flaky WiFi USB dongle on my work computer disconnects once every five or six hours and automatically reconnects to the wrong wireless network.  This means I have to keep calling my coworkers and asking them to fix my network, which they can't do if it breaks after 6 or 7 pm.

How can I configure network manager (via command line) to only ever connect to a wireless network with a particular ssid?  I've found plenty of solutions with a GUI, but running `ssh -X` fails on my personal computer (a windows machine).

Comment: Network Manager will just connect to any networks ***you have set up***. If it's connecting to a network you don't want, open your network settings and simply remove the erroneous connection. This is what Robert is saying,  but I think you're still misunderstanding the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can connect to a network with the command line:

```
nmcli con up id <connection name>
```

And list the available connections with:

```
nmcli con show
```

I'm however not sure if this is what you're asking - if you want to stop connecting to the wrong network you should just delete it. You can do this with:

```
nmcli con delete id <connection name>
```

Or by clicking on the networking indicator and deleting the connection from the "Edit Connections..." dialog.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, but my ssh connection went down yet again.

Thank you for your suggestion Robert, but when I type the command

`nmcli con list`

The network I want to prevent a connection to does not show up.  If I type 

`nmcli dev wifi list`

Then the connection I want to "blacklist" does show up.
As a result, 
`nmcli con delete id $network_name`
Just returns the message
`Error: Unknown Connection: $network_name.`

Comment: The wifi list is the list of available networks, Network Manager makes a connection when you connect to them. This indicates that your ssh session has no connections made.

If you have a graphical login account open and you're accessing the machine via ssh then the connections might be part of that graphical session and not seen by the ssh session. If this is the case you need to set the environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in your ssh session to match the graphical session so you can access the connections.

Comment: Should be `nmcli con up` instead of `nmcli up`. Not letting me edit the answer since it is less than 6 bytes of editing.

Comment: When run this command using SSH, i get this error " Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking."